# How to create a X.509 CA sample certificate for an Azure IoTHub Module?

Tags: python, x509, azure-iot-hub

I've been following the steps in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-python-module-twin-getstarted) to create a IoT hub Module, so I can experiment with module twins for my sample device. Every works well as long as I create the module with SAS tokens, as described in the tutorial.

But now, I'd like to be able to create a module by using a sample X.509 CA cert. The problem is that when I try to use the following to create my module:

```
module_client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_x509_certificate(cert, HOSTNAME, DEVICE_ID, MODULE_ID)
```

...with `cert` being the X.509 cert I created for my sample device using [those instructions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/tools/CACertificates/CACertificateOverview.md#iot-leaf-device-1) (i.e. `./certGen.sh create_device_certificate SampleDevice4`), I get the following error:

> ConnectOperation: completing with error UnauthorizedError('Connection
> Refused: not authorised.')

I know that my sample device cert is valid because I'm able to use it successfully in this [tutorial about device twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-twin-getstarted). So I assume that I need to create a new X.509 cert/key pair specifically for that module, as opposed to using the device cert. But I couldn't find how to create those. Does anyone know how to generate X.509 CA certs for a module as opposed to a device?

Answer (score 2):

I found that one can generate a module X.509 cert by using the following syntax:
`./certGen.sh create_device_certificate SampleDevice4\/mymodule`. Note that the slash must be escaped so that openssl can properly generate the common name (CN) for the cert.
As far as I can tell, this is undocumented behavior, so I don't know if this convention can be used reliably in the future. I left feedback on the tutorial to ask if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the feedback! Your feedback is valuable and shared with the content author to evaluate and update the doc as appropriate.